# Django djoser has two same urls

Tags: django, url, django-authentication, djoser

I'm reading about Djoser framework for Django.

I found that there are two url patters to include, both of which are the same:

```
urlpatterns = [
    (...),
    url(r'^auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    url(r'^auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
]
```

I thought that Django always takes the first match

How is it possible that the second path is picked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The urlpatterns you give are:

```
urlpatterns = [
    (...),
    url(r'^auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    url(r'^auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
]
```

From the usage of the function `include` you can see that those patterns are simply **including** other patterns. See [Including other URLconfs [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs).

If we look at the the urls from [`'djoser.urls'` (GitHub)](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/master/djoser/urls/base.py) they basically look like:

> ```
> router = DefaultRouter()
> router.register("users", views.UserViewSet)
>
> User = get_user_model()
>
> urlpatterns = router.urls
> ```

So basically with the usage of `include` this ends up generating a bunch of url patterns that look like `auth/users/...`

Moving to the patterns in [`'djoser.urls.jwt'` (GitHub)](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/master/djoser/urls/jwt.py):

> ```
> urlpatterns = [
>     re_path(r"^jwt/create/?", views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name="jwt-create"),
>     re_path(r"^jwt/refresh/?", views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name="jwt-refresh"),
>     re_path(r"^jwt/verify/?", views.TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name="jwt-verify"),
> ]
> ```

Which basically end up as `auth/jwt/create`, etc.

Looking at this the patterns are obviously **different** so there is no need to be concerned.